# Build a method that prints only a specific section of a file based array

Tags: java, arrays, file, methods, build

Good day guys.
I have to build a method that prints only a section of an array.

I set it up like this:

```
printArray1( intList, countOfInts, 3,  6 );
```

because it  denotes that it prints inclusively between array[3] and array[6].

My problem is that I do not know how to build into the method the sectioning off part.

This is what I've come up with.

```
static public int printArray1( int[] intList, int countofInts, ???, ???)
{
    if (countofInts >= 0 && (intList.length-9 <= countofInts && countofInts >= (intList.length-6) ))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < countofInts; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(intList[i] + "\t ");
        }
    }

return countofInts;
}
```

How to incorporate this sectioning off into the method?

Earlier in the program it reads a file then stores the info into an array. How do I get the method to only print that certain section of the array?

Comment: You have a loop with a start and an end; what's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArray1(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }, 3, 6);
            // prints: '3    4   5   6   '
}

static public void printArray1(int[] intList, int from, int to) {
    if (to > from && intList.length > to) {
        for (int i = from - 1; i < to; i++) {
            System.out.print(intList[i] + "\t ");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Inputs");
    }
}
```

Comment: Throwing an exception is usually better than failing silently - I know it's not strictly speaking silent but printing an error to the console isn't programmatically detectable.

Comment: I agree, I would have thrown an exception, but it was already using the console for output, so I stuck with that method. (Which is better than just ignoring the error completely, I only added that in as an afterthought.)

Comment: Nope.  It's not that kind of array.  It's file based.  The file is read and is fed into an array.  My method needs to be able to print only slots in the array.  I just used array[3] and array[6] to mean the slots in the array

Comment: what kind of array is it? you should be able to change int[] into any kind of array, and it will print it out.

Comment: @M21B8 It's an int array.  I just need the two numbers to denote that that is the only part of the array that will be printed.  I don't want to change the array, just print specific sections/lengths of it

Comment: Thats exactly what the code does. You say you want to from from element 3 to element 6 (inclusive) in the array, and it prints them out for you. Or did you mean you want it to print x number of elements from position y??

Comment: From element 3 to element 6 inclusive.  However the array isn't 1,2,3,4...etc.  It's an array that is built from a file.  Unless do you mean that that 1,2,3,4, represents the different slots in the array?

Comment: I used this: new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } just to test the array. just pass in your array of numbers, and it should work. The values in there could be anything, in any order, I used that sequence so it was easy to see it picked the right elements.

Comment: how do i pass in the array of numbers when it could any array?  I'm supposed to program this as if the numbers could be from any array. I would like the numbers 3, 6 to refer to the position in the array not the actual number in the array slot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43189/discussion-between-m21b8-and-weekzso)